# spliceAI not giving output value while running using vep (Variant Ensemble Predictor)

Tags: plugins, bioinformatics, prediction

While generating the predictions using spliceAI from vep, I am not getting any values.

I used this command to generate the output,

/vep -i input.vcf -o output.vcf --cache --force_overwrite --tab --no_check_variants_order --force --plugin SpliceAI,snv=spliceai_scores.raw.snv.hg38.vcf.gz,indel=spliceai_scores.raw.indel.hg38.vcf.gz

Below, are the examples of entries in the output file.

ENSEMBL VARIANT EFFECT PREDICTOR v109.3
Output produced at 2023-08-07 09:05:43
Connected to homo_sapiens_core_109_38 on ensembldb.ensembl.org
Using cache in /.vep/homo_sapiens/109_GRCh38
Using API version 109, DB version 109
ensembl-io version 109.4946a86
ensembl version 109.10baaec
ensembl-funcgen version 109.cba2db8
ensembl-variation version 109.18a12b6
...
Uploaded_variation Location Allele Gene Feature Feature_type Consequence cDNA_position CDS_position Protein_position Amino_acids Codons Existing_variation IMPACT DISTANCE STRAND FLAGS SpliceAI_pred
100017682 chr1:100017682 A ENSG00000117620 ENST00000370153 Transcript missense_variant,splice_region_variant 981 880 294 A/T Gca/Aca - MODERATE - -
100017682 chr1:100017682 A ENSG00000117620 ENST00000370155 Transcript splice_region_variant,3_prime_UTR_variant,NMD_transcript_variant 882 - - - - LOW - 1 - -

Is there any wrong in the input file? Could anyone help here?